# msbuild-bin/cl.exe doesn't know what std::apply is?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I was playing with VS2019 and found out that it works with clang.  So I installed clang and I've been having some issues with it working with VS2019.  However, this issue is only based on the compiler.  Seems that if I were to compile with the command line:

```
C:\Program Files\LLVM\msbuild-bin\cl.exe /std:c++17 source.cpp
```

Where source.cpp contains:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

void fn(int x)
{
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::tuple<int> x(1);
  apply(fn, x);
  return 0;
}
```

It barfs up:

```
clang-cl.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '/std:c++17' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
In file included from source.cpp:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\tuple:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\new:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\exception:7:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\yvals.h:7:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\yvals_core.h(334,2):  error: STL1000: Unexpected compiler version, expected Clang 7 or newer.
#error STL1000: Unexpected compiler version, expected Clang 7 or newer.
 ^
source.cpp(12,3):  error: use of undeclared identifier 'apply'
  apply(fn, x);
  ^
2 errors generated.
```

However, if I use:

```
"C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-cl" /std:c++17 source.cpp
```

All is well.

Thing is, VS2019 is using the former compiler executable.  How do I get it to use the latter?

The only thing I did to change the builder was to go and change this item:

[image: settings dialog]

Is there anything else I am to be changing?

Comment: 2014 isn't close enough to 2017 and LLVM isn't Clang.  You are seeing all the previously installed VS toolsets, not the Clang version you installed.  Go back to the VS2019 installer and add Clang support, ought to be listed as an option under the "individual components" section.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant.  Sorry, lost track of this thread.  I don't see anything in VS Installer that says "Clang support", or anything that looks remotely like that.